# I would like to use regex to insert specific characters in a regex expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to be able to use regex in Perl to insert characters into words.

So that the word "TABLE" would become "T%A%B%L%E%"

Can I ask for the syntax for such a feat?

Many thanks

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the string into characters then join them with what you want in between; also append that

```
my $res = ( join '%', split //, $string ) . '%';
```

A simple-minded way with regex

```
$string =~ s/(.)/$1%/g;
```

where with `/r` modifier you can preserve `$string` and return the changed string instead

```
my $res = $string =~ s/(.)/$1%/gr;
```

Comment: which version of Perl supports ````/r````?. It is throwing error for 5.10.1 RHEL

Comment: @stack0114106 Supported since 5.14.0.  See "_Non-destructive substitution_" in  [perl5140delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html)

Comment: @stack0114106 Yes, and it's just the right thing for some purposes.  (One example that comes to mind: using `s///` in `map`, where you want the changed string in the return list and thus had to type the lone `$_` after it, since `s///` alone returns the number of subs -- now with `/r` it nicely returns the changed string.)

Comment: yeah.. good to know.. I'll apply them.. I have only 5.10 in office workstation, will try this in my PC

Comment: did you try any other different solution using Perl for questions/53706983?.. Almost awk folks flood their answers for unix/shell/linux problems.. only few write Perl solutions.. so I'm not able to compare my solutions..

Comment: one such example is questions/53945896 where I wrote a lengthy one liner.. but Nahuel Fouilleul commented with a short and elegant answer.. that was a good learning from Nahuel..

Comment: @stack0114106 People do use `awk`, it is a good tool for certain types of problems. Sometimes questions specifically ask for it, too. Also, in many problems a few tools can be used (nearly) equally well.

Comment: @stack0114106 Your answer in 53706983 is a good approach; one has to accumulate those values. It is also nice how you do that. The only thing I see is that it can be cleaned up some, for readability.  As for the 53945896, Nahuel spotted that the number can be divided repeatedly by ten, so the solution came out short and clean (also because of properties of shell that were handy for that problem).  Your approach is good as well (and a nice idea), to do the same by counting characters, but in that case there happen to be simpler ways.

Comment: @stack0114106 Correction of my statement about 53706983 -- I don't actually see anything to "clean up" (other than cosmetics, to make it easier to read here, like spaces and layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command,

```
echo TABLE|perl -pe 's/\w/$&%/g'
```

This outputs `T%A%B%L%E%`

OR (in case your data is contained in a file)

```
perl -pe 's/\w/$&%/g' test.pl
```

You may replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` if you just want to replace with alphabets as `\w` matchs alphabets numbers and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-behind also

```
my $s = "table";

$s=~s/(?<=.)/%/g;

print $s;
```

If your version >5.14 you can use \K

```
$s=~s/.\K/%/g;
```